# Как кэшировать объект

Tags: java, кэширование

Есть 2 `int`'a нужно их кэшировать. Является ли в данном случае кэшированием сериализация?
Или как это вообще делать?

Comment: Вы явно не понимаете, чего хотите или что от вас требуется. Данные кэшируют, чтобы сэкономить на времени их расчета (расчитать один раз и не выполнять расчеты повторно) и/или получения (результат выполнения запроса к удаленному серверу). Бесцельное кэширование интов вам ничего не даст. Сериализация, в общем случае, здесь не причем.

Comment: Вот речь какраз про результаты запроса в базу.

Comment: сериализация используется для сохранения и восстановления состояния обьекта. Кеширование используется для того чтоб избежать выполнения ресурсоемких операций: вычисление (матем.), считывание данных из файла, получения данных из СУБД, передача данных по сети... Под кешированием можно понимать любое хранение информации которое позволяет получить результат быстрее чем при выполнении ресурсоемкой операции. 
Примеры: хранить в памяти конфигурацию приложения считанную из файла, скачивание инсталлера на локальный компьютер перед инсталляцией, при подсчете факториала хранить все промежуточные значени

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[@MaxBel](/users/12060/maxbel) В общем случае есть ключ (например параметры запроса), есть значение (результат запроса). При запросе проверяем в кэше наличие результата: если результат есть - отдаем, если нет - идем в базу и кладем в кэш, затем отдаем. В простейшем случае в качестве кэша может использоваться HashMap. Но обычно нужно предусмотреть политику инвалидации кэша (когда и как обновлять данные в кэше), ограничения кол-ва памяти используемой кэшем (все не закэшируешь, т.к. память ограничена), конкурентный дросутп к кэшу.